# @Value lateinit var is not instantiated only while called from test

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, junit, junit5, spring-boot-test

I am having trouble using my application.properties values while testing.

Here's my code:

```
@Repository
class RedisSubscriptionStore(): SubscriptionStore {
@Value("\${default.package}")
lateinit var defaultPackageForFCMInstance: String }
```

and this works as expected. It's used in my updateSubscription method with the correct value from application.properties

The problem is in my test when I use the class the value is not instantiated and throws an error

```
@SpringBootTest()
@Tag("integration")
internal class RedisSubscriptionStoreIntegTest @Autowired constructor(
    val objectMapper: ObjectMapper,
    val redisTemplate: RedisTemplate<String, String>
) {
    val sut = RedisSubscriptionStore(redisTemplate, objectMapper)

@Test
    fun `return 200 when updating subscription`() {
        sut.updateSubscription(updatedSub)

        //Assert
        val newlyUpdatedSub = getSubscription(updatedSub.peerID)
        Assertions.assertEquals(updatedSub, newlyUpdatedSub)
}
```

but this throws the error: lateinit property defaultPackageForFCMInstance has not been initialized

even though this works with the correct value:

```
@SpringBootTest()
    @Tag("integration")
    internal class RedisSubscriptionStoreIntegTest @Autowired constructor(
        val objectMapper: ObjectMapper,
        val redisTemplate: RedisTemplate<String, String>
    ) {

     @Value("\${default.package}")
     lateinit var defaultPackageForFCMInstance: String
}
```

so why is my defaultPackageForFCMInstance not initialized when calling from my test class? It obviously have a value, I've tried printing it out in the test class before calling it from sut

Comment: i cant see where sut ist coming from

Comment: It is the RedisSubscriptionStore, I have updated it now

Answer (score 1):

Your are instantiating the `RedisSubscriptionStore`

So there is no way for Spring to inject value. Either also pass the value in the constructor or use injecation in the test

```
 @Autowired
 var sut: RedisSubscriptionStore
```